# SQL case expression is not giving desired result

Tags: php, sql, case

I have the following situation. Sample data:

| OCTeamID (int) | OCTeamLastTime (datetime) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-01-21 00:37:23 |
| 3 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-01-21 00:37:23 |
| 5 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 |

What I am trying is the folowing:

When the Datetime value in the row of column `OCTeamLastTime` is higher dan the current datetime `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I want a SQL variable to be `Now` otherwise use the value from `OCTeamLastTime` as `CanDoOC`.

I am currently trying the folowing statement. But this gives me the result Now for every outcome.

```
SELECT OCTeamName, OCTeamID, OCTeamLastTime, (
    CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(OCTeamID) FROM OCTable WHERE OCTeamLastTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND OCTeamID = OCTeamID) > 0 THEN 'Now' ELSE OCTeamLastTime END
) AS CanDoOC
FROM OCTable
```

I want to use these results in a option list in php/html. Desired results based on above table:

```
<option data-subtext="Next OC: <?php echo $SelectOCTeam['CanDoOC']; ?>" value="<?php echo $SelectOCTeam['OCTeamID']; ?>"><?php echo $SelectOCTeam['OCTeamName']; ?></option>
```

It should create 5 options in this case. With Next OC: Now for the team with ID 1,3 and 5 and the `OCTeamLastTime` value for the other options.

Does anyone how to accomplish this? As what I did is not working and I cant think of any other way to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you just want the following query (without subquery)

```
SELECT OCTeamName,OCTeamID,OCTeamLastTime, 
    CASE WHEN OCTeamLastTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
      THEN 'Now' 
      ELSE OCTeamLastTime 
      END AS CanDoOC 
FROM OCTable
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I Think you are right but when testing I get a syntax error. #1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij 'THEN 'Now'
      ELSE OCTeamLastTime
      END) AS CanDoOC
FROM OCTable...' in regel 3

Comment: @Martin4523 I believe that the problem is in the return datatype. Could try to replace `OCTeamLastTime` with `CAST(OCTeamLastTime as VARCHAR(20))`?

Comment: Someone edited your answer. Left the () out so it seems. Tried it like that and this works and gives me my desired result. Thank you :) SELECT OCTeamName,OCTeamID,OCTeamLastTime, CASE WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= OCTeamLastTime THEN 'Now' ELSE OCTeamLastTime END AS CanDoOC FROM OCTable

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE` expression for this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN OCTeamLastTime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'Now'
    ELSE OCTeamLastTime
END AS CanDoOC
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Only slight modification to your query will help you get desired output

SELECT OCTeamName,OCTeamID,OCTeamLastTime,
(CASE WHEN  OCTeamLastTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'Now' ELSE OCTeamLastTime END) AS CanDoOC FROM OCTable